# How to compute diff with tree format

Tags: java, javers

Hi I would like to display diff like that and I'm wondering what's the best approach with Javers:

```
a.name          leftV <-> rightB
a.b[0].value    leftV <-> rightB
a.b[0].c.foo    leftV <-> rightB
```

As an example:

```java
public class A {
    public A(String name, List<B> listOfB) {
        this.name = name;
        this.listOfB = listOfB;
    }

    String name;
    List<B> listOfB = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class B {
    public B(int id, String value, C c) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Id
    int id;
    String value;
    C c;
}

public class C {
    public C(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    String address;
}

...
public void printGrpah() {
A a1 = new A("Foo", Arrays.asList(new B(1, "Bar", new C("Paris")), 
                                  new B(2, "Other", new C("Madrid"))));
A a2 =new A("Fooo", Arrays.asList(new B(1, "Bar2", new C("London"))));
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
Updated:
    name                 Foo <-> Fooo
    listOfB[0].value     Bar <-> Bar2
    listOfB[0].c.address Paris <-> London

Added
    listOfB[1].value     Other
    listOfB[1].c.address Madrid
```

I'm not looking for a final solution but more some clue to see where I need to plug my code:

- Do I need to implement my own visitor
- Plus custom ChangeProcessor
- ...

Thx in advance.

Christophe

Answer (score 1):

`ChangeProcessor` is designed for that kind of tasks. See http://javers.org/javadoc_2.0/org/javers/core/Javers.html#processChangeList-java.util.List-org.javers.core.changelog.ChangeProcessor-

For example, to get a simple change log, call:

```
 List<Change> changes = javers.calculateDiffs(...);
 String changeLog = javers.processChangeList(changes, new SimpleTextChangeLog());
 System.out.println( changeLog );
```